# Update the Resilience4J retry properties during runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, resilience4j

I am currently working on a spring boot application with a dependency on **resilience4j-spring-boot2**. I am using the Resilience4J retry in my code as follows:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private RetryRegistry retryRegistry; // Comes with resilience4j

    @Autowired
    private MyRetryService myretryService;

    @GetMapping("/test-retry")
    public void testRetry() {

       retryRegistry.retry("register-retry1", RetryConfig.custom().maxAttempts(9).waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                .retryExceptions(CustomException.class)
                  .failAfterMaxAttempts(true)
                  .build());

       // Can I update this already created retry's configuration now?    

       myRetryService.testRetry();
    }

}

public class MyRetryService {

     @Retry(name = "register-retry1")
     public void testRetry() {}

}
```

I want to update the configuration properties of the **register-retry1** retry either on runtime or within the code in a different place.

Note: The org I work for already has a Configuration management similar to Spring cloud config which we use to get the updated configuration. So, I wont be able to use resilience4j for spring cloud.